# Replace row in pandas with next row only when the entire row (each column) has NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame where I want to **replace only the rows with NaN values in *each column*** by the row below it. I tried solutions from multiple feeds and used **ffill** but that resulted in filling few cells and not the entire row.

```
     ss       s        h       b     sb
0   NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
1   3.0     NaN     14.0     NaN    8.0
2   9.0     8.0     23.0     NaN    2.0
3   NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
4   NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
5   1.0     6.0      7.0    11.0    3.0
```

**Expected output:**

```
     ss       s        h       b     sb
0   3.0     NaN     14.0     NaN    8.0
1   3.0     NaN     14.0     NaN    8.0
2   9.0     8.0     23.0     NaN    2.0
3   1.0     6.0      7.0    11.0    3.0
4   1.0     6.0      7.0    11.0    3.0
5   1.0     6.0      7.0    11.0    3.0
```

Comment: If use `df = df.bfill(limit=2)` it not working for `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups by testing rows with only missing values with cumulative sum by swapped order of column and pass to [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html):

```
df = df.groupby((df.notna().any(axis=1)).iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]).bfill()

print (df)
    ss    s     h     b   sb
0  3.0  NaN  14.0   NaN  8.0
1  3.0  NaN  14.0   NaN  8.0
2  9.0  8.0  23.0   NaN  2.0
3  1.0  6.0   7.0  11.0  3.0
4  1.0  6.0   7.0  11.0  3.0
5  1.0  6.0   7.0  11.0  3.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print ((df.notna().any(axis=1)).iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1])
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: So if I put a limit of 5? It won't replace s? Because I want to replace only if all values in the row are NaN with the next row. Even if next row have some NaN, that is okay.

Comment: @YashGhorpade - My question is limit=2 working for `s`, so not sure why there are NaNs in expected output.

Comment: The whole row has to be NaN to start replacing. Then you replace with the row below. First row is not replaced, since it is not only NaNs. Then Zeroth row has NaN copied from first row.

Comment: Because I want to replace the empty row exactly as other row, if the other row have some NaN, the original row should also have the same NaN.